# Explanation on Java Permutation program

Tags: java, permutation

this question might seem basic to some people but I've been analysing and dissecting this code without success as to how this [permutation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html) program by Robert Sedgewick prints the combination o f words or characters without using system.out.print in the methods perm1 and perm2. Any help or explanation for dummies is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This is the code under the link:

```
public class Permutations {
  // print N! permutation of the characters of the string s (in order)
  public  static void perm1(String s) { perm1("", s); }
  private static void perm1(String prefix, String s) {
      int N = s.length();
      if (N == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
      else {
          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
             perm1(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, N));
      }
  }
  // print N! permutation of the elements of array a (not in order)
  public static void perm2(String s) {
     int N = s.length();
     char[] a = new char[N];
     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
         a[i] = s.charAt(i);
     perm2(a, N);
  }

  private static void perm2(char[] a, int n) {
      if (n == 1) {
          System.out.println(a);
          return;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          swap(a, i, n-1);
          perm2(a, n-1);
          swap(a, i, n-1);
      }
  }  

  // swap the characters at indices i and j
  private static void swap(char[] a, int i, int j) {
      char c;
      c = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = c;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
     String elements = alphabet.substring(0, N);
     perm1(elements);
     System.out.println();
     perm2(elements);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's terrible code. Naming functions & variables, using `String` concatenations - evil.

Comment: But it does use them, only in their second overloads. You understand how the rest of it works, right?

Comment: @Sulthan It't probably a naive Java implementation of a well-known recursive permutation algorithm. Typical classroom code.

Comment: I thought I understood the rest of it but seeing Matzi's comment am beginning to doubt if my analysis is right. I know that its just a classroom code but am just more interested on  the way it works.

Comment: dimas, it will help your understanding to add `System.out.println("prefix " + prefix + "; s " + s);` as the first line in `perm1(String,String)`. Then you'll be able to track the recursive calls.

Comment: @dimas I would recommend you to take a debugger and step through the code, looking at the value of the variables.

Comment: Thanks Marko your suggestion helped me in understanding this code line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there:

```
if (N == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
```

`System.out.print` and `System.out.println` is basically the same, except the later prints a newline after the text.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I thought that line only prints out prefix if N is equal to zero? Meaning that there is no input detected?

Comment: It is a recursive function call, the N always decreasing and eventually reaches zero, and the function prints and terminates.